# evolocity package: Cannot download embedded model . RuntimeError: unexpected EOF

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, runtime-error, embedding

I am trying to follow a tutorial on how to use a package called "evolocity" (https://evolocity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/evolocity_nucleoprotein.html). Whenever I try to download the model that they used (ESM-1b), I run into trouble. When i run this code (in bold)

**import evolocity as evo
import scanpy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
evo.tl.velocity_graph(evo.datasets.nucleoprotein())**

I get the following message (the problem occurs when running **evo.tl.velocity_graph(evo.datasets.nucleoprotein())**):

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Applications/anaconda3/envs/epi_from_kuhn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esm/pretrained.py:33, in load_hub_workaround(url)
     32 try:
---> 33     data = torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url(url, progress=False, map_location="cpu")
     34 except RuntimeError:
     35     # Pytorch version issue - see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/43106
```

, which then traces back all the way to

```
File ~/Applications/anaconda3/envs/epi_from_kuhn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:1020, in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
   1018 assert key in deserialized_objects
   1019 typed_storage = deserialized_objects[key]
-> 1020 typed_storage._storage._set_from_file(
   1021     f, offset, f_should_read_directly,
   1022     torch._utils._element_size(typed_storage.dtype))
   1023 if offset is not None:
   1024     offset = f.tell()

RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 2191502174 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.
```

I have no idea how to fix this... can anyone help me? I cannot change the code since it comes from a made package...
I use anaconda to process the yml file to make an environment (seen below) and then export this environment to Jupyter Notebook.
I have MacOS Catalina, MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015), Processor: 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. Storage: I still have around 15GB available..

The yml file i used is given below (in the prefix I put ** where a username used to be, just to keep his/her privacy).

```
name: python_3.10.4_evo
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - abseil-cpp=20211102.0=hd638f34_2
  - absl-py=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - aiohttp=3.8.3=py310h90acd4f_1
  - aiosignal=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - astunparse=1.6.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - async-timeout=4.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=22.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h4e76f89_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h90acd4f_1005
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h0d85af4_4
  - c-ares=1.18.1=h0d85af4_0
  - ca-certificates=2022.10.11=hecd8cb5_0
  - cached-property=1.5.2=hd8ed1ab_1
  - cached_property=1.5.2=pyha770c72_1
  - cachetools=5.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - certifi=2022.9.24=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310hc55c11b_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.1.3=unix_pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - cryptography=38.0.3=py310h23bb4e6_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - fftw=3.3.10=nompi_h4fa670e_105
  - fonttools=4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=hd8bbffd_0
  - frozenlist=1.3.3=py310h90acd4f_0
  - gast=0.4.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=haf1e3a3_0
  - google-auth=2.14.0=pyh1a96a4e_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - google-pasta=0.2.0=pyh8c360ce_0
  - grpc-cpp=1.46.4=hea9d06c_3
  - grpcio=1.46.4=py310h2583000_3
  - h5py=3.7.0=nompi_py310h5555e59_102
  - hdf5=1.12.2=nompi_hc782337_100
  - icu=70.1=h96cf925_0
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=5.0.0=pyha770c72_1
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_3538
  - jpeg=9e=hca72f7f_0
  - keras=2.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.2=py310he9d5cce_0
  - krb5=1.19.3=hb49756b_0
  - lcms2=2.12=hf1fd2bf_0
  - lerc=3.0=he9d5cce_0
  - libabseil=20211102.0=cxx17_hd8326b1_2
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=hca72f7f_7
  - libcurl=7.86.0=h57eb407_1
  - libcxx=14.0.6=hccf4f1f_0
  - libdeflate=1.8=h9ed2024_5
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=h0678c8f_2
  - libev=4.33=haf1e3a3_1
  - libffi=3.3=h046ec9c_2
  - libgfortran=5.0.0=9_5_0_h97931a8_26
  - libgfortran5=11.3.0=h082f757_26
  - libnghttp2=1.47.0=h7cbc4dc_1
  - libpng=1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
  - libprotobuf=3.20.1=hbc0c0cd_4
  - libsqlite=3.39.4=ha978bb4_0
  - libssh2=1.10.0=h7535e13_3
  - libtiff=4.4.0=h2ef1027_1
  - libwebp=1.2.4=h56c3ce4_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=hca72f7f_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hfd90126_4
  - llvm-openmp=15.0.4=h61d9ccf_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h23ab428_1
  - markdown=3.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310h90acd4f_2
  - matplotlib-base=3.5.3=py310hfb0c5b7_0
  - mkl=2021.4.0=hecd8cb5_637
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310hca72f7f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310hf879493_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310hc081a56_0
  - multidict=6.0.2=py310h90acd4f_2
  - munkres=1.1.4=py_0
  - ncurses=6.3=h96cf925_1
  - numexpr=2.8.3=py310hdcd3fac_0
  - numpy=1.23.3=py310hc1140d4_1
  - numpy-base=1.23.3=py310h2a77c02_1
  - oauthlib=3.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=1.1.1s=hca72f7f_0
  - opt_einsum=3.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - packaging=21.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pandas=1.4.4=py310he9d5cce_0
  - pillow=9.2.0=py310hde71d04_1
  - pip=22.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - protobuf=3.20.1=py310hd4537e4_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.7=py_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyjwt=2.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=22.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyha2e5f31_6
  - python=3.10.4=hdfd78df_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-flatbuffers=1.12=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - python_abi=3.10=2_cp310
  - pytorch=1.13.0=py3.10_0
  - pytz=2022.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - pyu2f=0.1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - re2=2022.06.01=hb486fe8_0
  - readline=8.1.2=h3899abd_0
  - requests=2.28.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rsa=4.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - scipy=1.9.3=py310h09290a1_0
  - seaborn=0.12.0=py310hecd8cb5_0
  - setuptools=65.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - snappy=1.1.9=h225ccf5_2
  - sqlite=3.39.4=h9ae0607_0
  - tensorboard=2.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tensorboard-data-server=0.6.0=py310h23bb4e6_3
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tensorflow=2.9.1=cpu_py310h22f808f_0
  - tensorflow-base=2.9.1=cpu_py310h157eb30_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=2.9.1=cpu_py310he88cff4_0
  - termcolor=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h5dbffcc_0
  - typing-extensions=4.4.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.4.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2022f=h191b570_0
  - urllib3=1.26.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - werkzeug=2.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.38.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wrapt=1.14.1=py310h90acd4f_1
  - xz=5.2.6=h775f41a_0
  - yarl=1.8.1=py310h90acd4f_0
  - zipp=3.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=hfd90126_4
  - zstd=1.5.2=hcb37349_0
  - pip:
    - anndata==0.8.0
    - biopython==1.79
    - evolocity==1.0
    - fair-esm==2.0.0
    - igraph==0.10.2
    - joblib==1.2.0
    - llvmlite==0.39.1
    - louvain==0.8.0
    - natsort==8.2.0
    - networkx==2.8.8
    - numba==0.56.4
    - patsy==0.5.3
    - pynndescent==0.5.8
    - python-igraph==0.10.2
    - scanpy==1.9.1
    - scikit-learn==1.1.3
    - session-info==1.0.0
    - statsmodels==0.13.5
    - stdlib-list==0.8.0
    - texttable==1.6.4
    - threadpoolctl==3.1.0
    - tqdm==4.64.1
    - umap-learn==0.5.3
prefix: /Users/*****/opt/anaconda3/envs/python_3.10.4_evo
```

I tried to put a post so that someone can help me figure out what my RunTimeError is about and how I can move on with my code. Thank you :)